# sent and received message shows at the same time in socket.io and react native

Tags: react-native, socket.io

i have function called handleSend and recieving message only shows up when handleSend Function is triggered,as a result user on recieving end only see newly arrived message when he presses send button, I've just got started in react native so i'm unable to figure out whats wrong. Any help would be appreciated

```
import socket from "../components/socket";    
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);        
    const handleSend = () => {
      if (text.trim() !== '') {
        const newMessage = { text, sender: 'You', timestamp: new Date().getTime() };
        setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newMessage]);
  

        socket.emit('message', { text });
        onChangeText('');
      }
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      // Listen for "message" events from the serve
      socket.on('message', (data) => {
        const newMessage = { text: data.text, sender: 'Other', timestamp: new Date().getTime() };
        setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newMessage]);
      });
  
      // Clean up when component unmounts
      return () => {
        socket.disconnect();
      };
    }, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      // Scroll to the bottom of the ScrollView whenever messages change
      if (messages.length > 0) {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
      }
    }, [messages]);

return (
            <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} style={styles.chatContainer}>
              {messages.map((message, index) => (
                <View
                  key={index}
                  style={[
                    styles.messageContainer,
                    { alignSelf: message.sender === "You" ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start' },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.messageText}>{message.sender}: {message.text}</Text>
                </View>
              ))}
            </ScrollView>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are emiting the same event `message` and listening to same event . Thats why when you press send the socket listen to `message` event and show the message on sender side . try changing the name for event i.e to send message call the event as `sendMessage` and to listen for new messages try `onNewMessage` .

Comment: i did it as well, but i guess the problem was i wasn't using authentication system so i that might've been the problem, it solved after i added authentication to differenciate between both users. Thanks for help